# What's the difference between my application App constructor and the onStart method?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the class that I have:

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    public static DataManager db;

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new Japanese.MainPage();  // 1
    }

    public static DataManager DB
    {
        get
        {
            if (db == null)
            {
                db = new DataManager();
            }
            return db;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        App.DB.InitData(); // 2
    }
```

It's giving me a problem on first run in that the InitData sets up tables but the Japanese.MainPage() which needs tables runs before the tables have been set up.

Seems like the tables that are needed are not yet created.

Would it be reasonable to move the InitData into the App constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each platform calls `LoadApplication` to create an instance of your Xamarin.Forms App. You can see this in e.g. the `AppDelegate` class on iOS:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();   

    // Init additional components

    LoadApplication(new App());    
    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

As you can see at that point Xamarin Forms itself is initialized and a new instance of your application is created. The `App` class is instantiated in each platform-specific project and passed to the `LoadApplication` method which is when the `MainPage` is loaded and displayed to the user.

Since the `MainPage` you use uses data from the DB in its constructor your initialization in `OnStart` is too late in the lifecycle because it happens after the `MainPage` being created. Moving your DB initialization to the `App` constructor (before the `MainPage` assignment) would work in your scenario. Do ensure that any additional components you use that need to be initialized are initialized before the `LoadApplication` call in the platform specific code.

Answer (score 1):

On of the main reasons for having `OnStart` is to have the scenario when the app wakes up or put in the foreground again. and not only on its first run. So do you do not want to init your DB everytime you wake your phone up.

Plus as Steven said, `OnStart` gets called in later stages comparing with the constructor. And since you are doing some logic in the MainPage constructor that needs the DB then your app will give a null exception.

Two hints i would like to give you:

1. Make use of Dependency injection
2. If possible, try to avoid doing logic and business operations in any constructor.